# HTTPS (SSL) IE9 - FontAwesome does not display correctly, only squares are shown. | Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, font-face, webfonts, font-awesome

I am running an apache tomcat server, and I have SSL setup on my local, dev, and preproduction servers... I have FontAwesome setup on each of them successfully except for one small issue... when I view each server in IE9 in port 443, I cannot see the font, all I see is squares; however, if I look at the website in port 8080, I see all the fonts just fine. I have tried several things to fix this, which I will include below... Does anyone have any thoughts on what to try? It has been plaguing my website for weeks now and i'm banging my head against the desk...

List of things I have tried:

- I tried adding the "?#iefix" info at the end of the path.

`@font-face {

```
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}`

- I tried absolute pathing (localhost and local-IP)

`@font-face {

```
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src: url('https://localhost:8443/mywebsite/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
src: url('https://localhost:8443/mywebsite/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('https://localhost:8443/mywebsite/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('https://localhost:8443/mywebsite/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('https://localhost:8443/mywebsite/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}`

- I tried a linking straight to font-awesome site which technically works in IE, but it warns me about it being unsecured, and then Chrome completely blocks it, so that isn't a viable nor a good practice to do anyway...
- I reduced all the security settings in IE, checked and made sure that encoding is set to UTF-8.
- Someone told me that it might be to the fact that my local certificate is self generated and therefore didn't match the server, however my dev and preprod server have official certificates and still produce the same result.

I'm sure I have tried many other things, but as you can see, I have searched and searched on this issue, and either I find something that doesn't give much detail about how that person fixed the issue, or they just say... "never mind, I figured it out, thanks!" and they post no solution haha. I greatly appreciate any constructive input anyone has on this issue. Thanks a bunch! :)

ADDITIONAL NOTE: **Steps to reproduce** - If you setup apache tomcat, setup SSL with basic setup, install font-awesome, and view it in IE9. The issue should be there. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the problem, after weeks of trouble shooting, I discovered that our Tomcat web-inf web.xml file was causing issues with SSL and font-face. Basically we were originally apart of another "Main" repo on Git that had many apps, and many people were editing that web.xml file. Once we moved out of that repo, created our own repo, and web.xml file (which is practically empty), the problem was resolved. Hopefully this helps other people in the future who may have this issue.